# core data custom cell

Tags: ios, core-data, custom-cell

I try to write to out of the cells label but it not  work.

My Code is like this:

```
cell.idNummer.text = [NSString string With Format: @"%@", laddataId];
```

In core data is `laddataId` an integer 32. What should I write to display in label?

Comment: %@ is for writing out strings. Use %i for integers.

Comment: It does not work. I have to convert integer to string to display in labels but is not work?

Comment: [NSString stringWithFormat:"%i", laddataId]; should work. Put it into a string variable then log that. Then put it on your label. You might have broken your cell as well.

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

```
cell.idNummer.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", laddataId];
```

Please see [this](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/Strings/Articles/formatSpecifiers.html). It will help a lot.

Hope this helps.. :)

Comment: cell.idNummer.text = [NSString stringwithformat: @ "%i", laddataId]; not work.

Comment: Can you check the result of NSLog(@"%@", laddataId);? If it shows any warning please post that warning.

Comment: Output
2014-04-01 09:33:29.663 Laddata[876:60b] INIT (
    "<NSManagedObject: 0x10aa39780> (entity: Laddata; id: 0xd000000000040000 <x-coredata://26464B80-BC6F-4FA7-BCD2-67A2ABF35FB3/Laddata/p1> ; data: <fault>)",
    "<NSManagedObject: 0x10aa39be0> (entity: Laddata; id: 0xd000000000080000 <x-coredata://26464B80-BC6F-4FA7-BCD2-67A2ABF35FB3/Laddata/p2> ; data: <fault>)"
)
2014-04-01 09:33:29.671 Laddata[876:60b] self.objects:nor 2
2014-04-01 09:33:29.675 Laddata[876:60b] (null)
2014-04-01 09:33:29.675 Laddata[876:60b] id nummer (null)

Comment: Please share you full code at least I saw a code as comment before that part will help. And was it the output of NSLog(@"%@", laddataId);?

Comment: for (Laddata *obj in objects)
    {
        Laddata *obj = [self.objects objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        cell.vapen.text = obj.vapen;
        cell.kaliber.text = obj.kaliber;
        cell.datum.text = obj.datum;
        cell.idNummer.text = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%@",laddataId];
      
       NSLog(@"%@", laddataId);

Comment: 2014-04-01 09:33:29.663 Laddata[876:60b] INIT (
    "<NSManagedObject: 0x10aa39780> (entity: Laddata; id: 0xd000000000040000 <x-coredata://26464B80-BC6F-4FA7-BCD2-67A2ABF35FB3/Laddata/p1> ; data: <fault>)",
    "<NSManagedObject: 0x10aa39be0> (entity: Laddata; id: 0xd000000000080000 <x-coredata://26464B80-BC6F-4FA7-BCD2-67A2ABF35FB3/Laddata/p2> ; data: <fault>)"
)
2014-04-01 09:33:29.671 Laddata[876:60b] self.objects:nor 2
2014-04-01 09:33:29.675 Laddata[876:60b] (null)
2014-04-01 09:33:29.675 Laddata[876:60b] id nummer (null)
2014-04-01 09:33:29.676 Laddata[876:60b] (null)

Comment: What is Laddata and laddataId? I mean what type of object are they?

Comment: its not work 
cell.idNummer.text = [NSString stringWithFormat: @ "%i", laddataId];

Comment: I asked you something please answer that first.

Comment: Laddata is coredata entities.
laddataId is [newLoading setValue:[NSNumber numberWithInt:arc4random() % 100] forKey:@"laddataId"]; 
laddataId is attribute in core data.

Comment: What is newLoading is it also a core data entity?

Comment: textfield that save new data. A bit hard to explain everything, but I can email the project;

Comment: Anyone how to display the integer 32 from core data to the custom cell. 
This does not work?
cell.idNummer.text = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%i",laddataId];